# Networklink Refresh Without Closing Infowindow

Tags: kml

For the situation where the contents of the Infowindow are expensive to render, is there a way to get around the automatic closing of Infowindows when a Networklink is refreshed?  I'm trying to get around this restriction:

https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#balloonopennl

Answer (score 0):

When a NetworkLink refreshes all KML features associated with that Link are destroyed. If current "info window" description balloon is associated with the destroyed feature then it closes.

Only way to prevent the popup description balloon from closing is using the advanced [NetworkLinkControl](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklinkcontrol) to update only what changed in the KML by id.

Unfortunately there is not a lot of good documentation for using NetworkLinkControl correctly.

Here is a tutorial but the details are a little sparse.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates?hl=en